# How can I use social media to spread irrevocable insanity?

Tags: internet, social-media

I am Howard Lovecraft, a mediocre science fiction writer who has discovered an ancient text called the Necromonion. This text was written by Eldritch dieties and causes irrevocable insanity in all humans who lay eyes on it. I have decided to spread this manuscript to millions of people around the world in order to cause chaos and destruction across the human race. The reason? Some men just want to watch the world burn.

People don't read books anymore, so I have determined that the fastest way to spread this manuscript is through the internet by use of social media. Websites such as YouTube, Facebook, Twitter, etc, have connected people all across the world and allow them to keep in touch with each other. People who you knew in high school and no longer care about can now be updated about your current life. By uploading the Necromonion to my personal page, it can now reach others much more quickly and efficiently.

There is a problem however. The thing that causes the manuscript to be so effective at causing insanity also 
Stops it from reaching as many people as possible. When it's effects are discovered, my page can easily be blocked or removed, limiting it's availability. Worse yet, there is so much information on the internet aimed at grabbing people's attention. From cat videos, to memes, to political outrages, the media scene has become so over-saturated.

I need to be able to affect as many people as possible with the Necromonion by overcoming these hurdles. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Ad: try subliminal advertising on TV, radio, Internet, currency notes, road signs, newspapers... today offers buy 1 get 1 free.

Comment: Have you considered that a large proportion of your target audience already _is_ insane?

Comment: try sending unsolicited  advertisement email (spam)!

Answer (score 8):

## Impact and Speed are not the same goal

If your goal is to maximize the spread your message, the overall fastest way is not necessarily the most effective way.  As you note, once the existence of the [Yellow Note](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_King_in_Yellow) (as opposed to brown note) becomes a matter of common knowledge, the authorities will jump *immediately* to contain it.

So what you actually want is a technique where you can prepare, possibly for a great length of time, in secret, and then have a huge impact all at once.  It might not be 'fast', but there are things you can do with wider reach than the Internet.

## Hijack the mass media

It's [easier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max_Headroom_broadcast_signal_intrusion) than you think to [subvert](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broadcast_signal_intrusion#Cable_network_feed_intrusions) mass media.  Technically, there aren't really all that many protections in place to prevent it, and if you find the right spot, it's relatively easy to have a large impact.  The [Captain Midnight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_Midnight_broadcast_signal_intrusion) intrusion hijacked HBO for a large portion of the United States.

The reason these incidents aren't more common is afterwards, immense effort is spent investigating them and tracking down perpetrators.  But you don't care about any of that.  You just need a video of someone reading from the Pages in Yellow broadcasting for a few minutes.

So, since you don't care what comes next, hit the books and learn to be a good enough hacker to ...

## Hijack the Emergency Broadcast System

[Actually happened a few years ago.](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2013/02/bogus-zombie-apocolypse-warnings-undermine-us-emergency-alert-system/) By the time the authorities can get your signal shut down, it's already too late.  The feds administer the system, so its security is awful (like most of the rest of their security).  None of the weaknesses outlined [here](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2013/07/we-interrupt-this-program-to-warn-the-emergency-alert-system-is-hackable/) have probably been addressed.

## The 'S' in 'IoT' Is For Security

Movies and books like to give the impression that hacking things is hard.  The reality is being secure is hard, and the United States couldn't even keep the plans for nuclear weapons secure by physically sequestering everyone working on it in the desert.

Security is in general [pretty awful](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rnmcRTnTNC8).  In 2003 a guy broke into Windsor Castle and walked right up to the VIPs there for Prince William's birthday.  [He climbed one wall, then just acted like he belonged there.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aaron_Barschak)

You might think it would be hard to hijack the Emergency Broadcast System.  It's not as hard as you think.

Comment: "The 'S' in 'IoT' Is For Security"  It's not even noon yet, and I'm pretty sure that's going to be the best laugh I have all day. Thank you!

Comment: To be fair, it's not my joke.  But I'm glad you liked it :)

Answer (score 5):

Buy ads. It is implausible that ads would drive people insane,* so you'll probably reach a bunch of people before anyone figures this out. You can buy targeted ads to reach out to people who will be less missed at first, and geolocated ads if you want to see if you can take out a small town or whatever.

Serve up inoffensive content at first. Get a following (may be tricky if you are truly mediocre). Then flip on the madness. This might get you caught.

Just laying eyes on it drives people nuts? Put up a few copies in the middle of Times Square. You may need accomplices to hold them up on posterboards, like a protest. Then toss a bunch of puppies off a tall building right next to them. You'll madden a ton of people just because Times Square, plus the news will probably broadcast this across the globe. You will most likely get caught. Maybe try to get it up on a livestream (although doing so without driving yourself mad may be tricky).

*Well, to some extent they already seem to, but not in the manner you are discussing.

Answer (score 3):

You have the same problem that viruses have, you want to infect hosts, make them infectious to others, but otherwise remain undetected. Then (less like a virus) you want to release the destructive payload in a centrally coordinated way.

The added challenge here is that the final exposure requires reading a book rather than a simple sentence. This takes some investment of time and you want to time things so that most people make that investment at roughly the same moment.

## A computer game

A computer game is an artifact that you can share in viral fashion, but still control centrally to release the Necromicon at a predetermined time. It also has the added benefit that you can create a fictional world where a Necronomicon is an entirely plausible artifact, no matter how macabre it looks.

In the first stage you just create a game that is as addictive as you can make it. Pull out all the stops, make it a cross between World of Warcraft, Farmville, Candy Crush and Clash of Clans. Ensure that people post about their progress to social media, or about the cool stuff they've found in this new game universe. Maybe develop a few different games, so that you can hit different markets. Give the games an immersive environment with some mystery, and crucially, center everything around mystery books. Players find mystery books and read them to unlock new content and find hints to the puzzles that have been bugging them (a bit like the journals in the Myst series). From day one, give hints about the ultimate book, the Necronomicon, which will provide the clues required to unlock the central tomb.

Release new content periodically. Spread a rumour that there's a big update coming that will feature the Necromicon. Include it as a locked book, with a special code, to be found at a particular time and a particular place. Everybody gets the code at the same moment, starts reading at the same moment, and the world burns.

Answer (score 2):

I think the most effective way to spread the text is a three or more fold approach.

The first approach is to take a page from the flat earth playbook.  Spread rumors and memes that simultaneously declare the existence of the text a hoax and that it contains the absolute truth of the universe.  This step is to get the phrasing and words into the global consciousness.  You can see how successful it was for the flat-earthers so it will work for Hastur too.

The second step is to construct a vast internet path to the actual text.  The real text should be deep in the dark web.  With many sites containing fragmentary pieces of the actual text mixed with fraudulent contributions.  The maze of paths to this site requires the hunters to shift their way through a complex web of internet clues to guide them to the eventual site.  In this step, you are using our all too human allure of the difficult and forbidden to compel people to infect themselves with madness.  They'll believe they are either debunking the idea of searching for ultimate truth, but they'll keep at it the way humans have also sought to scratch niggle-some itches in their psyches.

The third step is to get governments, professional associations, the PTA, FDA, KGB, Mossad, anyone you can, to declare that it doesn't exist and that no one should try to find it, its dangerous.

Fourth and following steps all pretty much the same thing over and over.  Get celebrities to comment about it -- how stupid it is, how sexy it is from someone to look for it, how smart people don't look for it, how smart people are looking for it  Embedded it in advertising campaigns, Have Nancy Reagan style just don't look for its campaigns.  This step keeps it in the global zeitgeist and, inevitably, one of the different approaches will be attractive to someone and they'll look for it.  The whole of social media influencers, sensing the opportunity to make a buck, or get famous, will lend their voices to search and sharing clues.  Soon the entire world will be hunting sharing the small fragments of the text they find.

Answer (score 1):

Lovecraft,

You should consider reaching out to companies that have risen from the ashes of Cambridge Analytica.  With hyper-personalization and targeting that allows for each person's distinct psychological vulnerabilities to be narrowed in on, you could easily launch a global campaign across various social platforms.

You would need to amass a substantial amount of content across various maddening topics.  People seem to enjoy their own flavors of outrage and fixation, so be sure not to skimp on the variety inflammatory articles, images, and even better... doctored videos that you produce.

Algorithms can help you identify vulnerable targets as well as the topics that have the greatest likelihood to tip subjects towards mental and emotional instability.  Isn't wonderful that so many people share so much information online?  Just ripe for the taking.

Of course you would want to start off subtly, disseminating articles that gently prod at insecurities, fears, and unhealthy fixations.  As you begin to infiltrate the consciousness of the masses (aligned with their own preferred flavors), you can ratchet up intensity until you get an adequate fever pitch.

It would also help to connect like-minded individuals, so they can chat and commiserate to their hearts content, aiding each other in expunging the last lingering shreds of their sanity. Facebook groups, hashtags, and social figures of leadership would be ideal.  You may need to create your own at the onset, but soon enough, people will pick up much of that grunt work for you.

Once fanaticism is piqued, it's time to start teasing your greatest release.  You'd need to tie it in to the multitude of targeted fears and insecurities, but once people have become true believers, it will require far less heavy lifting.

Sure, it will require quite a bit of capital to get off the ground, as well as many man hours, but it will be well worth the effort in the long run.

Best of luck, and might I add that we aren't too terribly far off from this as it is...

Yours Truly,